# Create audio path between Virtualboxes with snd-aloop

Tags: drivers, sound, virtualbox, pulseaudio, alsa

My goal is to send an audio signal from a Virtualbox and record it in a different Virtualbox. Both are running Ubuntu 16.04 and so is the host.

I thought that I could start snd-aloop in the host (index 2) and then tell one VB to use hw:2,1,1 to send audio and the VB2 use hw:2,0,1 to receive the audio.

In the VB settings, Audio I can choose "Host Audio Driver" and "Audio Controller". I have selected "ALSA Audio Driver" but snd-aloop is not in the list of Audio Controllers.

Is what I'm trying to do a reasonable idea or am I going to get in trouble with different machines controlling the same audio card?

Can I achieve and audio path between Virtualboxes  in any other way?

Comment: Did you create the loopback device before starting VirtualBox?

Comment: @CL Yes, I did create a loopback device with 8 subdevices.

Comment: have you tried enabling vt-d in bios and in virtualbox for this specific emulation?

Comment: @tatsu yes, it is enabled in BIOS and VB.

Comment: and downloading and running this: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.22/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126.vbox-extpack  then re-creating the emulation  and once launched do this :  http://www.osboxes.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/ot/virtualbox-tools-1.jpg ?

Comment: @tatsu I had the guest additions installed before I asked the question.